# Does Passing STL Containers Make A Copy?

Tags: c++, c++11

I can't remember whether passing an STL container makes a copy of the container, or just another alias. If I have a couple containers:

```
std::unordered_map<int,std::string> _hashStuff;
std::vector<char> _characterStuff;
```

And I want to pass those variables to a function, can I make the function as so:

```
void SomeClass::someFunction(std::vector<char> characterStuff);
```

Or would this make a copy of the `unordered_map` / `vector`? I'm thinking I might need to use `shared_ptr`.

```
void SomeClass::someFunction(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<char>> characterStuff);
```

Comment: Shouldn't your single colons `:` be double colons `::`?

Comment: @David yes, they should be double colons `::`

Comment: To prevent copy pass by reference (preferably const reference).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends. If you are passing an *lvalue* in input to your function (in practice, if you are passing something that has a name, to which the address-of operator & can be applied) then the copy constructor of your class will be invoked.

```
void foo(vector<char> v)
{
    ...
}

int bar()
{
    vector<char> myChars = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
    foo(myChars); // myChars gets COPIED
}
```

If you are passing an *rvalue* (roughly, something that doesn't have a name and to which the address-of operator & cannot be applied) and the class has a move constructor, then the object will be moved (which is not, beware, the same as creating an "alias", but rather transferring the guts of the object into a new skeleton, making the previous skeleton useless).

In the invocation of `foo()` below, the result of `make_vector()` is an *rvalue*. Therefore, the object it returns is being *moved* when given in input to `foo()` (i.e. `vector`'s move constructor will be invoked):

```
void foo(vector<char> v);
{
    ...
}

vector<char> make_vector() 
{ 
    ...
};

int bar()
{
    foo(make_vector()); // myChars gets MOVED
}
```

Some STL classes have a move constructor but *do not have a copy constructor*, because they inherently are meant to be non-copiable (for instance, `unique_ptr`). You won't get a copy of a `unique_ptr` when you pass it to a function.

Even for those classes that do have a copy constructor, you can still force move semantics by using the `std::move` function to change your argument from an lvalue into an rvalue, but again that doesn't create an alias, it just transfers the ownership of the object to the function you are invoking. This means that you won't be able to do anything else with the original object other than reassigning to it another value or having it destroyed.

For instance:

```
void foo(vector<char> v)
{
    ...
}

vector<char> make_vector() 
{ 
    ...
};

int bar()
{
    vector<char> myChars = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
    foo(move(myChars)); // myChars gets MOVED
    cout << myChars.size(); // ERROR! object myChars has been moved
    myChars = make_vector(); // OK, you can assign another vector to myChars
}
```

If you find this whole subject of lvalue and rvalue references and move semantics obscure, that's very understandable. I personally found this tutorial quite helpful:

http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html

You should be able to find some info also on http://www.isocpp.org or on YouTube (look for seminars by Scott Meyers).

Comment: Although all the answers here I consider correct enough to be marked as the answer, I found yours the most intriguing.

Comment: Thank you! Anyway the best way to grasp this stuff after reading some good material is to try and play with it a little. I suggest you to write a small toy class with a move constructor and a copy constructor, pass it in to some functions by value and see which one is invoked (either by debugging or by putting some `cout << msg` inside). You will also notice that sometimes no constructor at all is invoked, like when returning from `make_vector()` above: that's an optimization compilers usually do

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it'll copy the vector because you're passing by value. Passing by value always makes a copy or move (which may be elided under certain conditions, but not in your case). If you want to refer to the same vector inside the function as outside, you can just pass it by reference instead. Change your function to:

```
void SomeClass::someFunction(std::vector<char>& characterStuff);
```

The type `std::vector<char>&` is a reference type, "reference to `std::vector<char>`". The name `characterStuff` will act as an alias for the object referred to by `_characterStuff`.

Comment: Nitpick: I don't think passing by value *always* makes a copy. For instance, when passing a temporary by value, I am pretty sure that the compiler is allowed to elide the copy.

Comment: @BjörnPollex Yes! I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 5):

C++ is based on values: When passing object by value you get independent copies. If you don't want to get a copy, you can use a reference or a `const` reference, instead:

```
void SomeClass::someFunction(std::vector<char>& changable) { ... }
void SomeClass::otherFunction(std::vector<char> const& immutable) { ... }
```

When the called function shouldn't be able to change the argument but you don't want to create a copy of the object, you'd want to pass by `const&`. Normally, I wouldn't use something like a `std::shared_ptr<T>` instead. There are uses of this type by certainly not to prevent copying when calling a function.