# Are the following two expressions equivalent involving a map

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a variable of type:

```
std::map<int,std::vector<std::string>> m;
```

Now statement A is:

```
m[2].push_back("SomeString");
```

and statement B is:

```
  std::vector<std::string> t = m[2];
  m[2]=t.push_back("SomeString");
```

I wanted to know if B is a proper equivalent of A.

The reason I ask this is because at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074289/does-passing-stl-containers-make-a-copy) on SO it states that STL objects make copies. However statement A to me seems like it returns a reference. Any suggestions on what is happening here?

Comment: Your examples won't even compile.

Comment: s/pushback/push_back ?

Comment: This does not make a lot of sense, even if you ignore obvious typos

Comment: @nijansen why doesnt it make sense ?

Comment: Have you tried to compile first ? You'll get compile errors for 3 out of the 4 lines you gave.

Comment: Statement A and B doesn't match the specified type: `m[2].push_back("...");` is correct for `std::map<int,std::string>`

Comment: @hivert thanks for pointing that out. This question was in my mind and I was curious about the internal working. Just fixed it. Hope the downvote fairy gets appeased.

Comment: I will assume `typedef std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> map` for brevity. Then what is `map t = m[2]` (`m` being of type `map`) supposed to mean - what is `m[2]` supposed to mean? `map` has keys of type `std::string` not `int`. What is `m[2]=t.push_back("")` supposed to mean? `std::vector<T>::push_back` does not even return a value

Comment: m[2] is just a consideration (assume the map is already populated)

Comment: It seems like a genuine question and the OP has fixed the typos. Keeping the downvote here is not justified.

Comment: @KillianDS Fixed the typo. As I mentioned earlier the question was in my mind and I quickly jolted it down.

Comment: @Rajeshwar that's part of the problem isn't it, you didn't even take the time to try some of it out yourself, that would have answered half of your questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `operator[]` on `std::map< class Key, class Value` is used to get the value that corresponds to a specific key (actually, it returns a reference, but w/e). In your case you will use it like this:

(**code piece 1**)

```
std::map<std::string,std::vector<std::string>> m;
<...>
std::string the_key_you_need("this is the key");
std::vector< std::string > value = m[the_key_you_need];
value.push_back(<...>)
```

which is NOT the same as:

(**code piece 2**)

```
std::map<std::string,std::vector<std::string>> m;
<...>
m[the_key_you_need].push_back(<...>);
```

because in the first one, you are making a *copy* of `m[the_key_you_need]` named `value`, and pushing the new string *into the copy*, meaning it will not end up in `m`. The second one is the proper way to do it.

Also, `m[<something>] = value.push_back(<something_else>)` will not work, because `vector::push_back()` returns void. If you want to do it this way, you will need to:

(**code piece 3**)

```
std::map<std::string,std::vector<std::string>> m;
<...>
std::string the_key_you_need("this is the key");
std::vector< std::string > value = m[the_key_you_need];
value.push_back(<...>)
m[the_key_you_need] = value;//here you are putting the copy back into the map
```

In this case, code pieces 2 and 3 are indeed equivalent (but code piece 2 is better because it doesn't create an unnecessary copy).

Comment: Stating that it returns a reference explains a lot. The reason i asked was that i read that the STL works with copies it always returns a copy and makes a copy of the passed object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074289/does-passing-stl-containers-make-a-copy. Maybe I misunderstood the answer

Comment: @Raje, I've edited the answer a bit to clarify it further. You can check that map's `operator[]` indeed returns a reference [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)

Comment: So the question is whether in this case its returning a copy or a reference ?